# Is &<'_> something the same as &something in function signature?

Tags: rust

To implement fmt::Display, a piece of rust code may like this

```rust
impl fmt::Display for Weekday {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(...)
    }
}
```

But isn't that <'_> redundant, since `let x: _ = 1` means the same as `let x = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<'_>` generic lifetime parameter is not required here. The compiler will treat the code with and without the same.

However, having the lifetime annotated in the type is preferred even when it is just a placeholder. There is a [`rust-2018-idioms`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/groups.html) lint - [`elided-lifetimes-in-path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/lints/listing/allowed-by-default.html#elided-lifetimes-in-paths) - that will enforce that `<'_>` is there. This is encouraged because it makes it more clear that an additional lifetime is present so it is clear when borrows are happening. This generally aids understanding and helps avoid lifetime errors.

Comment: Note however that there are some places where `'_` makes a difference - mainly when dealing with trait objects, where e.g. `Box<dyn Trait>` is `Box<dyn Trait + 'static>` and different from `Box<dyn Trait + '_>`.